# Configure a linux router to forward some LAN hosts' traffic and DNS over an OpenVPN tunnel?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a GNU/Linux box that I've set up as a router for my home network. I have three network interfaces...

- ppp0 is the upstream connection
- lan is the local network
- nordvpn is the VPN tunnel

I'm using nftables for the firewall and I'm running a caching DNS server (dnsmasq). DNS requests from the LAN are intercepted and sent instead to the DNS server on the router. So far so good, however...

By default NordVPN routes *all* upstream traffic through the VPN tunnel, and if it's configured this way it works, but I don't want this. I want most traffic to the internet to go over the ppp0 interface, with traffic from specific LAN hosts to be sent via the VPN instead. DNS requests for the hosts using the VPN should be directed to the VPN provider's DNS servers rather than the local server.

I've read various articles discussing how to do similar (but not identical) things, and so far I've not been able to make it work. I'm clearly doing at least one thing wrong. As I understand it I should be able to mark packets in the firewall, and then send those packets over the nordvpn interface using a custom routing table. What I have so far is as follows...

I have added the following line to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.

```
5     nordvpn
```

In order to prevent openvpn from setting up it's own routes I have added these lines to `/etc/openvpn/client/nordvpn.conf`.

```
route-noexec
script-security 2
route-up /etc/openvpn/client/mkroute.sh
```

I believe I need to disable reverse path filtering on the nordvpn interface to make things work? This is the script that openvpn uses to set up my routing.

```
#!/bin/bash

TABLE="nordvpn"
MARK="0x5"

die() {
  echo "Error: $1"
  exit 1
}

[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] || die "Not running as root"

ip route flush cache || echo "error 1"
ip route flush table "$TABLE" || echo "error 2"

ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev lan src 192.168.2.1 table "$TABLE" || echo "error 3"
ip route add $route_vpn_gateway dev lan src $ifconfig_local table "$TABLE" || echo "error 4"
ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway dev "$dev" table "$TABLE" || echo "error 5"
ip rule delete fwmark "$MARK" || :
ip rule add fwmark "$MARK" lookup "$TABLE" || echo "error 6"
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.nordvpn.rp_filter=0 || echo "error 7"
```

Finally, this is my nftables script.

```
flush ruleset

define i_wan = ppp0
define i_nordvpn = nordvpn
define i_lan = lan

define p_dns = 53

define a4_nordvpn_dns_1 = 103.86.96.100
define m_nordvpn = 5

define h4_nimrod = 192.168.2.21

table ip ip4_firewall {

  set s_inet_nordvpn { type ipv4_addr; elements = { $h4_nimrod }; }

  chain c_here_to_wan { tcp flags syn tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu; accept; }
  chain c_here_to_nordvpn { tcp flags syn tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu; accept; }
  chain c_here_to_lan { accept; }
  chain c_wan_to_here { ip protocol icmp accept; drop; }
  chain c_wan_to_lan { ip protocol icmp accept; drop; }
  chain c_nordvpn_to_here { ip protocol icmp accept; drop; }
  chain c_nordvpn_to_lan { ip protocol icmp accept; drop; }
  chain c_lan_to_here { accept; }
  chain c_lan_to_wan { tcp flags syn tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu; accept; }
  chain c_lan_to_nordvpn { tcp flags syn tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu; accept; }

  chain preroute_nordvpn {
    udp dport $p_dns mark set $m_nordvpn dnat $a4_nordvpn_dns_1
    tcp dport $p_dns mark set $m_nordvpn dnat $a4_nordvpn_dns_1
    oif $i_wan mark set $m_nordvpn
  }

  chain prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100
    ip saddr @s_inet_nordvpn goto preroute_nordvpn
    iif $i_lan oif $i_wan udp dport $p_dns redirect
    iif $i_lan oif $i_wan tcp dport $p_dns redirect
  }

  chain postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100
    oif $i_nordvpn masquerade
    oif $i_wan snat <my public IP address>
  }

  chain input { type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop
    ct state established,related accept
    ct state invalid drop
    iif vmap {
      lo: accept,
      $i_wan : jump c_wan_to_here,
      $i_nordvpn : jump c_nordvpn_to_here,
      $i_lan : jump c_lan_to_here
    }
    log prefix "Unhandled input: " drop
  }

  chain output { type filter hook output priority 0; policy drop
    ct state established,related accept
    ct state invalid drop
    oif vmap {
      lo: accept,
      $i_wan : jump c_here_to_wan,
      $i_nordvpn : jump c_here_to_nordvpn,
      $i_lan : jump c_here_to_lan
    }
    log prefix "Unhandled output: " drop
  }

  chain forward { type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop
    ct state established,related accept
    ct state invalid drop
    iif . oif vmap {
      $i_lan . $i_wan : jump c_lan_to_wan,
      $i_wan . $i_lan : jump c_wan_to_lan,
      $i_lan . $i_nordvpn : jump c_lan_to_nordvpn,
      $i_nordvpn . $i_lan : jump c_nordvpn_to_lan,
    }
    log prefix "Unhandled forward: " drop
  }
}
```

Once configured I have the following.

```
[root@cerberus ~]# ip rule ls
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from all fwmark 0x65 lookup nordvpn
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
[root@cerberus ~]# ip route ls
default dev ppp0 scope link 
10.0.0.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src <my public IP address> 
10.8.0.0/24 dev nordvpn proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.12 
192.168.2.0/24 dev lan proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1 
[root@cerberus ~]# ip route ls table nordvpn
default via 10.8.0.1 dev nordvpn 
10.8.0.1 dev lan scope link src 10.8.0.12 
192.168.2.0/24 dev lan scope link src 192.168.2.1 
[root@cerberus ~]# ip rule ls
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all fwmark 0x5 lookup nordvpn
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

When enabled clients assigned to the VPN have their DNS lookups fail. It seems the requests are sent over the VPN tunnel, but the replies arrive in the input chain rather than the forward chain and don't make it to the clients. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: 1. Shouldn't you be using the `route` chain with the `output` hook for `mark set`? 2. Why do you have `oif` in your `prerouting` rules? 3. Why would you use `goto` instead of `jump` for `ip saddr @s_inet_nordvpn` / `preroute_nordvpn`?

Comment: @Tom Yan 1. I only want to send traffic from the LAN through the VPN. Forwarded traffic will traverse the prerouting, forward and postrouting, and not the output chain? 2. In preroute_nordvpn chain I'm using oif because I don't want to mark traffic from the LAN to my router. In the prerouting chain oif is to ensure only DNS requests to the wan are intercepted, I don't think it's interfering with anything? 3. I'm using goto rather than jump to prevent rule processing returning to the prerouting chain from the preroute_nordvpn chain when it completes.

Comment: Never mind. I wasn't really familiar with nftables so yeah I was wrong, about goto v.s. jump, and where you should do `mark set` (though I don't think you are doing it right either; it's obvious that you want to do it for all `ip saddr @s_inet_nordvpn` traffics and you are repeating it; looks like you should do it with a `type filter hook prerouting priority mangle` chain, though I'm not sure). But I'm quite certain that the `oif` in your `prerouting` rules is a/the problem, as `oif` only makes sense after routing. (And I've confirmed that it is not a no-op match in that case.)

Comment: Try to stop dnsmasq and see ;-)

Comment: `because I don't want to mark traffic from the LAN to my router` I don't think that's covered by the `prerouting` hook at all (but the `input` hook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

```
  chain preroute_nordvpn {
    udp dport $p_dns mark set $m_nordvpn dnat $a4_nordvpn_dns_1
    tcp dport $p_dns mark set $m_nordvpn dnat $a4_nordvpn_dns_1
    oif $i_wan mark set $m_nordvpn
  }

  chain prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100
    ip saddr @s_inet_nordvpn goto preroute_nordvpn
    iif $i_lan oif $i_wan udp dport $p_dns redirect
    iif $i_lan oif $i_wan tcp dport $p_dns redirect
  }
```

to:

```
  chain fwmark { type filter hook prerouting priority -150
    ip saddr @s_inet_nordvpn mark set $m_nordvpn
  }

  chain lan_dns {
    ip saddr @s_inet_nordvpn dnat $a4_nordvpn_dns_1
    redirect
  }

  chain lan_dnat {
    udp dport $p_dns goto lan_dns
    tcp dport $p_dns goto lan_dns
  }

  chain prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100
    iif $i_lan goto lan_dnat
  }
```

Comment: It works! Still a little testing to do, but my IP reports as the VPN's IP. If I take $h4_nimrod out of @s_inet_nordvpn it returns to my actual public IP. Great work, many thanks :)

Comment: The results from DNS leak tests are as expected too. Thanks again! :)